# Hide error unable to allocate memory for pool

Tags: php, codeigniter

I realize the following error: “unable to allocate memory for pool” in mx loader appears because of high server activity and I should increase my memory in php.ini. However is there a way to hide such messages?

It wouldn’t be friendly to show such ugly red errors to website visitors it may freak them out. Is there a way to mask such errors and similar errors (if they occur) in a friendlier fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the PHP error messages by setting the *environment* in index.php to *testing* or *production*. This turns off all PHP error reporting.

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

The templates for the error messages are in *application/errors* - you can change the appearance of the messages here.

Comment: Thank you, will setting the environment to production hide such (database) errors? As they really shouldn't be displayed to user

Comment: It will turn off all PHP error reporting; to hide database errors you'd need to set _db_debug_ in _application/config/database.php_ to `FALSE`: `$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;`